# Anonymous Functions on Event Handlers not activating Styling

Tags: javascript, html

I have been experimenting with a technique for using event listeners which I found here on the Stack Overflow.

My own problem is that I am trying to retrieve the element ids of a couple of elements (retrieved by testing for id name) and isolate any styling/changes to just those elements (there are multiple elements that may have events occur on them).

Because I don't know which elements could have events occur on them I found the biggest issue was gathering and passing the id of the elements I wanted to pass to the listener. I believe I have found a way to overcome that using an array and an if else statement. Then I found a new problem...

I narrowed the issue using this example down to choice A or B. Choice A needs to modify an element with styling and choice B doesn't. In this example I've been able to gather an id and pass it to the listening function but for some reason the anonymous functions in the listener are not firing to modify choice A despite the event seemingly being passed successfully to the listening function and I am asking for help to find out why. If I explicitly hard code an id to the listener the program works!

Any help anyone could provide would be great and very much appreciated.

```js
function listen(elem, evnt, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener) { //W3C DOMS.
    elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent) { //IE DOM 7
    var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
    return r;
  }
}

function attachListeners() {

  var selectors = document.querySelectorAll("div");

  for (var i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
    selectors[i].addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
      var id_of_clicked_element = event.target.id
    });

    // var id_of_clicked_element = document.activeElement.id;
    if (id_of_clicked_element = 'touch_me') {
      var touch_div = id_of_clicked_element;
    } else if (id_of_clicked_element = 'What_about_me') {
      touch_div = id_of_clicked_element;
    }
  }


  //var touch_div = document.getElementById('touch_me');
  //  If you uncomment the line above and comment out the bit   
  //   above the program works


  listen(touch_div, 'touchmove', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML = "Being Touched" + event.targetTouches.length;
    touch_div.style.background = 'green';
  }, false);

  listen(touch_div, 'touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    touch_div.innerHTML = "touchstart";
    touch_div.style.background = 'green';
  }, false);

  listen(touch_div, 'touchend', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML = "Thanks";
    touch_div.style.background = '#CCFF66';
  }, false);

  listen(touch_div, 'click', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML = "Hey - touch not Click!";
    touch_div.style.background = 'red';
  }, false);

  listen(touch_div, 'onmouseup', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML = "Hey - that was a Click!";
    touch_div.style.background = '';
  }, false);
}

window.onload = attachListeners;
```

```html
<div id="touch_me"> Touch Me!</div>
<div id="What_about_me"> What About Me!</div>
```

Comment: Why pass ID instead of the object?

Comment: Thanks very much you were right. I'm also grateful to Matus below because I needed to see the code for it to truly make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your if statement you are just getting ID of the element not the whole element. You should change it to:

```
    if (id_of_clicked_element === 'touch_me') {
      var touch_div = document.getElementById(id_of_clicked_element);
    } else if (id_of_clicked_element === 'What_about_me') {
      touch_div = document.getElementById(id_of_clicked_element);
    }
```

Comment: Conditions use `==` or `===` not `=`

Comment: Thanks I missed that.

Comment: Thanks very much for the theory and the code Matus that's exactly what I needed. Like a lot of things once someone shows you it just makes perfect sense. In practice I couldn't get it to work with your suggestion of using multiple equals signs, I only got it working using single equals signs  - otherwise I received reference errors. It works now though and that's the main thing. Once again thank you - this has held me up for a while  - I will need to learn more about objects and the nature of javascript. in the future.